# jspm install err TypeError: must start with number, buffer, array or string

Tags: node.js

`jspm install`

The error that I faced

```
TypeError: must start with number, buffer, array or string
         at fromObject (buffer.js:158:9)
         at new Buffer (buffer.js:62:10)
         at decodeCredentials (E:\Exinda_Cloud\qx-cloud-fe\node_modules\jspm\node_modules\jspm-github\github.js:55:14)
         at Object.GithubLocation (E:\Exinda_Cloud\qx-cloud-fe\node_modules\jspm\node_modules\jspm-github\github.js:112:19)
         at Object.exports.load (E:\Exinda_Cloud\qx-cloud-fe\node_modules\jspm\lib\registry.js:73:56)
         at new RegistryPath (E:\Exinda_Cloud\qx-cloud-fe\node_modules\jspm\lib\config\loader.js:264:33)
         at Config.read (E:\Exinda_Cloud\qx-cloud-fe\node_modules\jspm\lib\config\loader.js:127:26)
         at E:\Exinda_Cloud\qx-cloud-fe\node_modules\jspm\lib\config.js:100:26
         at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:9)
         at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:443:11)
         at startup (node.js:139:18)
         at node.js:968:3
```

> err  Unable to load registry github
>
> warn Installation changes not saved.

Comment: You need to configure your GIT first, Try executing `jspm registry config github` before you try your `jspm install` command

Answer (score 2):

This is how resolved the issue.

Enter the command **jspm registry config github** and enter your credentials then retry the command. If everything goes well the command should produce below similar response

C:\Users\Umamaheswaran>jspm registry config github

Would you like to set up your GitHub credentials? [yes]:yes

If using two-factor authentication or to avoid using your password you can generate an access token at https://github.com/settings/tokens. Ensure it has public_repo scope access.

Enter your GitHub username:XXXX
Enter your GitHub password or access token:

Would you like to test these credentials? [yes]:yes
ok   GitHub authentication is working successfully.
ok   Registry github configured successfully.